# React Native Navigator does not render initialRoute - blank screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, navigator

I'm new to navigator so maybe there is something small I'm missing I'm hoping someone can point out.

My app worked before adding Navigator. After adding a basic implementation, I only see a blank screen and no errors in the debugger.

Here's my app before Navigator:

```js
import React, {
  Component, PropTypes
}
from 'react';
import {
  Text, View, Navigator, StyleSheet
}
from 'react-native';

import ReasonSelect from './components/ReasonSelect'
import ShippingDetails from './components/ShippingDetails'
import Confirmation from './components/Confirmation'

export
default class CardReplacement extends Component {
  render() {
      return ( < View > {
            eligibilityLoading &&
              < View style = {
                {
                  marginTop: 30,
                  paddingLeft: 15
                }
              } >
              < Text > Loading... < /Text>
      </View >
          } {
            !eligibilityLoading &&
              < ReasonSelect / >
          } < /View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's my add after adding Navigator (I do see this console log working):

```js
import React, {
  Component, PropTypes
}
from 'react';
import {
  Text, View, Navigator, StyleSheet
}
from 'react-native';

import ReasonSelect from './components/ReasonSelect'
import ShippingDetails from './components/ShippingDetails'
import Confirmation from './components/Confirmation'

export
default class CardReplacement extends Component {

  renderScene(route, navigator) {
      if (route.name == "Replacement") {
        console.log('working')
        return <ReasonSelect navigator = {
          navigator
        }
        />
    }
    if(route.name == "Shipping"){
      return <ShippingDetails navigator={navigator} / >
      }
      if (route.name == "Confirmation") {
        return <Confirmation navigator = {
          navigator
        }
        />
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (   
   <View>
    {eligibilityLoading &&
      <View style={{marginTop: 30, paddingLeft: 15}}>
        <Text>Loading...</Text >
        < /View>}
    {!eligibilityLoading &&
          <Navigator
            style={{ flex:1 }} 
            initialRoute={{name: "Replacement"}}
            renderScene={this.renderScene}
          / >
      } < /View>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to simplify even more and I still can't see anything if I change my Navigator to:

```js
     < Navigator
     style = {
      {
        flex: 1
      }
    }
    initialRoute = {
      {
        name: "Replacement"
      }
    }
    renderScene = {
      (route, navigator) => {
        return <ReasonSelect / >
      }
    }
    />
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer my own question: My conditional `elegibilityLoading` is causing problems. I need to refactor this this. But I'm still not sure why. I can't even wrap Navigator in a View or the screen will turn white again. Would love to know the technical reason for this.

```js
render() {
    if(eligibilityLoading){
      return (
        <View style={{marginTop: 30, paddingLeft: 15}}>
          <Text>Loading...</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }

    return (   
      <Navigator
        style={{ flex:1 }} 
        initialRoute={{name: "Replacement"}}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just explaining why your conditional is causing you issues:

```
<View>
  {eligibilityLoading &&
  <View style={{marginTop: 30, paddingLeft: 15}}>
  <Text>Loading...</Text >
< /View>}</View> //Pretty sure this will evaluate to <View>true</View> which is why it's showing a blank screen
          //same logic applies for the !eligibilityLoading part
```

Comment: But before adding Navigator, the conditional worked as expected. When eligibilityLoading == true it would render Loading text and when eligibilityLoading == false it would render the view component.